# PDFlib is broken on Mac OS X if Perl > 5.10

Tags: perl, pdf, osx-lion, pdflib

We've been using PDFlib  to generate PDFs from text files. It has worked fine until we upgraded our Macs to Lion. PDFLib fails now generating this message:

```
Can't load '/[path to directory]/pdflib_pl.dylib' for module pdflib_pl:
```

> dlopen(/[path to directory]/pdflib_pl.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /[path to directory]/pdflib_pl.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture 
>   at /usr/local/ActivePerl-5.14/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 195.
>
> at /[path to directory]/perl586/pdflib_pl.pm line 22
>
> Compilation failed in require 
>   at /[path to directory]/reportpdf.pl line 11.
>       BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /[path to directory]/reportpdf.pl line 11

The dylib's architecture is i386 according to lipo:

```
$ lipo -info pdflib_pl.dylib
```

> `Non-fat file: pdflib_pl.dylib is architecture: i386`

That dylib is from version 7 (or earlier?) of PDFlib. It was was installed by a previous developer, so I don't know exactly where it came from. The upgraded version of PDFLib, version 8, does not seem to have a dylib included for perl.  Should I compile a new dylib? Source is available from PDFlib for their lite version at least, and I'm comfortable with compiling stuff, but I'm hoping there is simpler solution.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try?

```
>> perl -MCPAN -e 'install PDFLib'
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to have some dependencies. "Set up build environment without MacOSX10.5 SDK (will build i386 binaries)

PDFLib requires the pdflib package from http://www.pdflib.com/ version
4.0 or higher to be installed, and the perl interface "pdflib_pl.pm"
enabled to be able to work properly. Please install that before trying
to install this module.

Warning: No success on command[/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.14/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
  MSERGEANT/PDFLib-0.14.tar.gz
  /usr/local/ActivePerl-5.14/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK"

Comment: I manually copied the latest PDFLib into the lib directory in my @INC and ran the MCPAN again. This time it completed without error and said that `PDFLib is up to date (8).` Running the script results in the same error as I had in the first place.

Comment: @TonyAdams - If you got error about line 11 or 22, then you have to find what is on those lines and follow that lead...